# C++20 Module Interface & #pragma warning

Tags: c++, visual-c++, warnings, c++20, c++-modules

I can't seem to get VC++'s `#pragma warning` to work in module interfaces. Has anything changed?

Example:

```
module;

#pragma warning( push, 0 )
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ntstatus.h>
#pragma warning( pop )

export module WarningsTest;
export void TestFn();
```

```
1>Scanning sources for module dependencies...
1>Module.ixx
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\ntstatus.h(66,14): warning C4005: 'STATUS_WAIT_0': macro redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winnt.h(2510): message : see previous definition of 'STATUS_WAIT_0'
```

Additionally, how does one do this warning management for header inclusion as a module? i.e.

```
module;

#pragma warning( push, 0 )
import <Windows.h>;
import <ntstatus.h>;
#pragma warning( pop )

export module WarningsTest;
export void TestFn();
```

will result in warnings, as well. Is this part of the same bug or is there a specific way to disable warnings from external module headers?

Comment: To the second question: From what I recall during standardization of modules, the `import ...` statements, whether modules or headers, must come _first_ in the module definition -- I think even before macros or pragmas can be evaluated. I'm not sure if that changed by the time it was actually approved since it went through several revisions, but my suspicion is that the `#pragma ...` approach you are hoping to do is simply incompatible with modules. Modules are meant to be consistent and self-contained -- so I don't see how a `#pragma` mixed with an `import` would work given that.

Comment: @Human-Compiler I can do `#if 0` fine and it skips resolving that import. Might just be an MSVC thing.